# JQ reshape nested array

Tags: json, jq, reshape

I have an issue with jq and nested arrays, I cannot get why it is creating multiple objects:

```
echo '{
    "first": [
        {
            "second": {
                "id": 1,
                "third": [
                    {
                        "value": "aa"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "bb"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}' | jq '.first[].second | {id: .id, prop: .third[].value}'
```

This is returning:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "prop": "aa"
}
{
  "id": 1,
  "prop": "bb"
}
```

But I would like to have:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "prop": ["aa", "bb"]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put values in an array :

```
jq '.first[].second | {id: .id, prop: [.third[].value]}'
```

Comment: ❤️ I was going crazy

Answer (score 1):

Use the `map` builtin to transform the array into just `.value`s:

```sh
jq '.first[].second | {id: .id, prop: .third | map(.value)}'
```

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "prop": [
    "aa",
    "bb"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/td594KsXmj)